# XCode 9 - Clearing Device List to clear out Hard Drive Space?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was developing this iOS app using xCode 9, and I deployed it to (via XCode and Cable) over 40 different devices so that my users can test it at their own convenience.

I noticed that whenever I registered a device under my Provisioning Profile, it would take ~100mb or so of memory in my HD. I was fine with this, but now that the app is done being used, I'd like to clear the devices in my Provisioning Profile (or where ever the OS saves it) and get some of my HD Space back.

So far, I went to my developer account, then to the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, and finally, in the devices.

There was no option to Delete it (as I would only get that once my developer program expires), only to Disable. I've disabled all the devices, and I don't know how to re-download or refresh the Provisioning Profile in XCode.

Does anyone how to clear out devices in the Developer Profile? I could really use a whole lot of the disk space it took.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481549/what-can-i-delete-from-library-developer-xcode-folder

Comment: @rmaddy freed about 3.5 GB worth of space. Still would want more.